# Error in Delete SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

ok guys i need your help im having trouble in mysql syntax

i have a table of

```
CREATE TABLE tblemployee(
`employeeID` int(5) Primary key not null,
`employeefname` varchar(15),
`employeelname` varchar(15),
);

CREATE TABLE tbltimpunch(
`employeeID` varchar(10),
`dateoftime` datetime,
`timein` time,
`timeout` time
);
```

and i want to delete this:

```
DELETE FROM tblemployee t,tblemployee e 
WHERE t.employeeID = e.employeeID 
and e.employeelname ='EnterNumber'
and dateoftime ='2013-07-02' 
and timein ='09:00:00' 
and timeout = '15:00:00'
```

this is my error:

> Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE t.employeeID = e.employeeID and e.employeelname
>   ='EnterNumber' and dateoft' at line 1

Comment: Please copy & paste the error you're getting.

Comment: What happens when you run the DELETE statement? What error do you receive?

Comment: If there's an error, paste the error in.

Comment: Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE t.employeeID = e.employeeID and e.employeelname ='EnterNumber'
and dateoft' at line 1

Comment: what do you mean by t.employeeID = e.employeeID? id doesn't make sense, try this 
`DELETE tblemployee  
WHERE employeelname ='EnterNumber'
and dateoftime ='2013-07-02' 
and timein ='09:00:00' 
and timeout = '15:00:00'`

Comment: sorry for not including the error hope you can help me with this one =(

Comment: i call the table ID i refer tbltimepunch as t and tblemployee as e.. so im calling t.employeeID = e.employeeID

Comment: This is wrong. You should have foreign keys setup and have the database CASCADE delete all `tbltimpunch`

Comment: well its working if its a select statement but in delete its not working..and btw i dont want to set up the primary key in tbltimepunch cause it will not acceptnull value you get my point? if you can just help me in the query =(

Comment: You should have a primary key in `tbltimepunch` named `id` that auto increments.. this is a standard practice..

Comment: do you want to delete from tbltimpunch or tblemployee or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing:

```
DELETE FROM tblemployee t,tblemployee e
```

These are both same tables, so thats why you're getting error. Guess it should be:

```
DELETE FROM tbltimpunch t,tblemployee e
```

Because you're deleting from multiple tables, query should be something like this:

```
DELETE t, e 
FROM tbltimpunch t 
INNER JOIN tblemployee e  
WHERE CAST(t.employeeID AS SIGNED) = e.employeeID  
AND e.employeelname ='EnterNumber' 
AND dateoftime ='2013-07-02'  
AND timein ='09:00:00'  
AND timeout = '15:00:00'
```

Comment: nice answer, but check the table definitions! how do you check an int with a string(varchar)? +1

Comment: yeah, my bad :) totaly overlooked that.

Comment: you did a right job dude, I just surprised like you, it just need a casting, add it :)

Comment: aw sorry i havent notice that =(..and about that varchar i missed type it it supposed to be int >.<

Answer (score 0):

Your tables should be setup in a *RELATIONAL* way:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee_times` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timein` datetime NOT NULL,
  `timeout` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `employee_id` (`employee_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `employee_times`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `employee_times_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Now when you simply delete from `employees`, the effect cascades into `employee_times`.

Also notice the table names:

`employees` = multiple employees

`employee`_`times` = single employee, multiple times

This is how you make a database relational.